# How can I solve this complicated MySQL Query problem

Tags: php, mysql

I am in a problem with a complex PHP MySQL query. I hope you can help me with it. I do my best to explain everything as well as possible and clearly.

- Here are 2 tables (activity table and activityParticipant Table)
- Here is a one-to-many relationship
- The registration is stored in the activity Participant table. For clarity, I have also included activity table in the explanation.

**Tabel activity**

```
activityId      name            
1               Activity-01
2               Activity-02
3               Activity-03
4               Activity-04
```

**Tabel activityParticipant**

```
activityParticipantId   activityId      personId    date            
55                      1               28115       2020-05-28
66                      2               34496       2020-05-28
67                      3               34635       2020-05-28
88                      4               12992       2020-05-28
```

The query to be written here must meet these conditions.

- A Person wants to register with an activity (example: activityId -> 1).
- Then you get the personID of the person (example: 235625)
- In the activityParticipant table, it must be checked that the person has not previously been registered with the activity to which he wants to register and also check if the same person has already been registered with another activity, but that the 2 activities do not fall on the same date.

Unfortunately I am unable to solve this problem. I hope you can help me with it.

thanks in advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite easy - all you need is an UNIQUE constraint over the combination of the two involved columns:

```
ALTER TABLE activityParticipant
ADD UNIQUE (activityId, personId);
```

Now when you try to insert a row where there is duplication with another row (like person 235625 wants to register for a second time for activity 1), the query will fail with error.

To solve the "no two activities for the same person on the same date" issue you can do the same for *personId* and *date*:

```
ALTER TABLE activityParticipant
ADD UNIQUE (date, personId);
```

Now person 235625 can't register for two different activities on the same date.

Comment: Don't you need to add another constraint for the date and the personId?

Comment: Thx for your explanation and tips. I am not very good at writing sql queries. I will try to use ur tips to solve this problem